# Vim: don't spell check Javadoc or code snippets in package.html

Tags: java, vim, javadoc

When using vim to do spell checking in a `package.html` file it will flag words it doesn't recognize in code snippets (`<code>...</code>`) and inside Javadoc tags (e.g., `{@link com.example.Foobar}`).  How do I make Vim's spell checker ignore those words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed using the `@NoSpell` directive of [Vim syntax highlighting](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html).

Put this into a file somewhere:

```
" Don't spell check embeded Javadoc tags and code snippets in package.html
syn region javadoc_tag start=+{@+      end=+}+         contains=@NoSpell
syn region javadoc_see start=+@see  *+ end=+\( \|\$\)+ contains=@NoSpell
syn region code        start=+<code>+  end=+</code>+   contains=@NoSpell
```

Then add this line to your vimrc file:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile package.html source /PATH/TO/FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Neovim and using Tree Sitter for highlighting, there is a special `@nospell` capture group: https://neovim.io/doc/user/treesitter.html#treesitter-highlight-spell

You can use this capture group by defining a custom `queries/{lang}/highlights.scm` query file (where `{lang}` is the desired Tree Sitter language) that applies the `@nospell` capture group to the desired syntax tree nodes.

For example, if you want to disable spell-checking in Markdown files (which I believe should be set anyway by default in `nvim-treesitter`), you can add this simple query in `queries/markdown/highlights.scm` anywhere in your runtime path (e.g. `stdpath('config')`):

```lisp
(code_fence_content) @nospell
```

This query matches any `code_fence_content` anywhere in the syntax tree and captures it with the group `@nospell`, which Neovim in turn recognizes for disabling spell checking on the contents of that node.

See [the TS docs](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/using-parsers#query-syntax) and [Neovim docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/treesitter.html#treesitter-query) for more detail on writing Tree Sitter queries.